# NSArray out of bounds check

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray, indexoutofboundsexception

noobie question.. What is the best way to check if the index of an NSArray or NSMutableArray exists. I search everywhere to no avail!!

This is what I have tried:

```
if (sections = [arr objectAtIndex:4])
{
    /*.....*/
}
```

or

```
sections = [arr objectAtIndex:4]
if (sections == nil)
{
    /*.....*/
}
```

but both throws an "out of bounds" error not allowing me to continue

(do not reply with a try catch because thats not a solution for me)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (array.count > 4) {
    sections = [array objectAtIndex:4];
}
```

Comment: Damn.. im so stupid.. of course!! an array gets filled sequentially. i made my head a mess. Thanks mate +1

Comment: I think objective-c language is a little bit stupid here. I would be more comfortable with if `[array objectAtIndex:outOfBounds]` returned `nil` instead of crashing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an integer index (e.g. `i`), you can generally prevent this error by checking the arrays bounds like this

```
int indexForObjectInArray = 4;
NSArray yourArray = ...

if (indexForObjectInArray < [yourArray count])
{
    id objectOfArray = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexForObjectInArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind NSArray is in **sequential order** from **0 to N-1** items

Your are trying to `access` `item` which has **exceeded limit** and a `array` is `nil` then compiler would throw out of `bound error`.

**EDIT** : @sch's answer above shows how can we check if NSArray has required ordered item present in it or not.

Comment: An array of N items is in sequential order from 0 to N-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MIN` operator to fail silently like this `[array objectAtIndex:MIN(i, array.count-1)]`, to either get next object in the array or the last. Can be useful when you for example want to concatenate strings:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"Some", @"random", @"array", @"of", @"strings", @"."];
NSString *concatenatedString = @"";
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<10; i++) {  //this would normally lead to crash
    NSString *nextString = [[array objectAtIndex:MIN(i, array.count-1)]stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    concatenatedString = [concatenatedString stringByAppendingString:nextString];
    }
NSLog(@"%@", concatenatedString);
```

Result: "Some random array of strings . . . . . "