# Get NSRange from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsrange

So I have NSArray that contains objects like `{117, 22}{http://t.co/7l3oiMDQt3}` and I want to get `117` and `22` I tried to use `ObjectAtIndex:` and the app was crashed and then added this:

```
if(array.count > 0) {                                           
   NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

and still the app crashes.

is there's any other way to get the `NSRange` location and length from the array?

**EDIT:**

The objects inside the array is `NSDataDetector` that gets the links form a string.

it says this when it crashes:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
***
```

Comment: so what...? what's an "object like {117, 4}{said}`"? Did you use a debugger to investigate the reasons your app crashed?

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` does not often crash without a reason. Are you sure your array contains two objects?

Comment: ^ what he said.. Try NSLog(@"%@", array[0]);

Comment: When you say, descriptively "the app crashes", what **exactly** does it tell you is the reason for termination? We're not mind readers.

Comment: @Tommy sorry about that I added what it says when it crashes

Comment: @JonKayin well that's it. Your array contains 1 element, at index 0. You are trying to access the **second** element, at index 1. That's incorrect. (Also, you should have pasted the error message [which is informative and kind of obvious...] into Google **days before** falling back to asking here. Stack Overflow is full of solutions to this very same problem. Don't be lazy.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArray out of bounds check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715261/nsarray-out-of-bounds-check)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the possible duplicate is not solving my problem.

Comment: As others have stated, the crash is because even with the bounds check, you are accessing an array element that is out of bounds. objectAtIndex:0 would be correct for the bounds check you have implemented.

Comment: have you checked your data carefully. I think it isn't NSArray type

Answer (score 1):

Your check can still be out of the array range :

if(matc.count > 0) {
   NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]); //not 1
}

Comment: nothing happens, the same result as there's no `objectAtIndex`

Comment: Wait.. What is matc? Shouldn't that be array?

Answer (score 0):

You should never arbitrarily check an index in an array without knowing the exact length. Whenever you're dealing with an array with a varying length, you should do something like this to prevent trying to access an index that doesn't exist:

```
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < array.count; index++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
}
```

You'll never have an out of bounds exception doing the above.